# Input a excel sheet into a table in Oracle using Python - TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, string, oracle, byte, cx-oracle

> Hello, I have a excel sheet like and I am trying to add it into my SQL table. I have columns 'APPRAISER' and 'TIN'. I keep getting this error "TypeError: expecting string or bytes object"

```
krn = pd.read_excel("KRN TIN.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl', sheet_name = 'Sheet1',parse_dates=False)

tin = krn.loc[:,['APPRAISER','TIN']]
tin = tin.drop_duplicates()
print(tin.shape)
print(tin.head())
    
rows = [tuple(x) for x in tin.values]
rows


conn2.close()
create_table='''CREATE TABLE TEMP_KRN (KRN VARCHAR2(255) KRN_TIN VARCHAR2(255))'''
create_table='''CREATE TABLE TEMP_KRN (KRN VARCHAR2(255), KRN_TIN VARCHAR2(255))'''
conn2 = cx_Oracle.connect(user=xx, password=x_pwd, dsn=dsn_tns2, encoding="UTF-8")
cur=conn2.cursor()

cur.execute(create_table)
cur.execute('grant select on KSG_LOSS_RPTG_SB.TEMP_KRN to PUBLIC')
cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO TEMP_KRN(KRN, KRN_TIN) VALUES (:1, :2)''',rows)
conn2.commit()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-caff8b3d7041> in <module>
      7 cur.execute(create_table)
      8 cur.execute('grant select on KSG_LOSS_RPTG_SB.TEMP_KRN to PUBLIC')
----> 9 cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO TEMP_KRN(KRN, KRN_TIN) VALUES (:0, :1)''',rows)
     10 conn2.commit()

TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

> I added the excel into a table and the table into my SQL but its not working. I tried changing the table name, drop existing tables, changing `tuple(x)` to `str(x)`. I tried everything related to my problem but it seems to be something else. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Check the cx_Oracle [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) and examples for the correct data format to use.  Run the examples e.g [bind_insert.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/bind_insert.py). Make sure your `rows` value has a similar format.  Also check the doc about Predefining Memory Areas with `setinputsizes()`, since this can improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me.

[The data needs to be with format which in this case was a STRING. Just make sure your columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loBYu.png)

Each of my columns needed to be with a correct format (which you can see on my error that is string). So I change the data format on each of my columns using .astype(str) as you can see on the picture. Hope it helps. Simple mistake that took me more than a day to figure it out.